# 16.04 server: Byobu doesn't respect TERM setting

Tags: byobu

I installed [byobu](https://www.byobu.org/) with [anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) on server 16.04, things seems to work fine and I can connect from a MacOS machine.

```
byobu --version
byobu version 5.133
tmux 2.9
```

But even though `$TERM` is shown correctly, colors inside a byobu session are still messed up:

```
echo $TERM #inside byobu
xterm-256color
```

If I do invoke the following way, colors works as expected:

```
TERM=xterm-256color byobu
```

I already set the following but no use:

```
cat ~/.byobu/.tmux.conf
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
cat ~/.byobu/profile.tmux
source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/profiles/tmux
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

Why is that, and how to fix?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @K7AAY i am running Ubuntu 16.04, server version, connecting to it from a MacOs.

Comment: Please click [edit] when you have facts to add, so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should explicitly export TERM as ``xterm-256color'' in the profile of your login shell. This workaround works in my ubuntu 20.10 server.